# firebase token contains email as null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-signin

i am trying to add authentication using firebase google provider, but after authentication iam getting the firebase token in which the email is null, other things such as name, photourl is present.

i tried to add the scopes to the provider function but its not working

```
  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    googleProvider.setCustomParameters({
      prompt: "select_account",
    });
    googleProvider.addScope("profile");
    googleProvider.addScope("email");

    await handleLogin(googleProvider);
  };
```

iam not able to fetch the email my login function is this:

```
const handleLogin = async (signInFunction: any) => {
    try {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, signInFunction);
      // setUser(result.user);
      console.log("set user", setUser);

      console.log(`${signInFunction.providerId} user `, result.user);

      

      // Get the ID token directly
      const idToken = await result.user.getIdToken();
      console.log("idtoken is : ", idToken);

      // Extract relevant information from the authentication result
      const { uid, displayName, email ,photoURL } = result.user;
      console.log("this is uid :", uid);

      // Create an object with the data you want to send to the backend
      const userData = {
        id: uid,
        displayName: displayName,
        email: email,
        photoURL: photoURL,
      };

      // Make a POST request to your backend using the Fetch API
      const postResponse = await fetch(`${accountServiceBackendUrl}/users`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userData),
      });

      if (postResponse.ok) {
        console.log("User data sent to backend successfully");
        console.log("user authenticated from backend means.");
        setUser(result.user);
        console.log("this is the after user :", setUser);
        console.log("user data", userData);

        setDbUser(true);
      } else {
        console.error("Error sending user data to backend:", postResponse.statusText);
      }

      // Make a GET request to your backend using the Fetch API for single user
      const SingleUser = await fetch(`${accountServiceBackendUrl}/users/${uid}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
        },
      });

      if (SingleUser.ok) {
        const SingleUserData = await SingleUser.json();
        console.log("User data received from backend successfully as a single user", SingleUserData);
        setDbUser(true);
      } else {
        console.error("Error fetching user data from backend:", SingleUser.statusText);
      }

      // Make a GET request to retrieve user information after login
      const getResponse = await fetch(`${accountServiceBackendUrl}/users`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
        },
      });

      if (getResponse.ok) {
        const getUserData = await getResponse.json();
        console.log("User data received from backend:", getUserData);
        setDbUser(true);
      } else {
        console.error("Error fetching user data from backend:", getResponse.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during authentication or fetch:", error);
    }
  };
```

i tried reading the docs but still iam not able to find any solution. please help!